# dhclient connecting to wlan0 after wpa-supplicant setup polls infinitely

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, wpa-supplicant, wpa, dhclient

I just wanted to try out how to connect to my WIFI WPA2 via terminal.

Therefore I created "/etc/wpa_supplicant"

```
network = { 
  ssid = "nameOfWifi"
  psk = "passwordNumberThatIFoundOnTheWifiHardware"
}
```

Then I started following command

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -D nl89211
```

No Errors thrown. Up to the last step

Launching command to connect to my Wifi now

```
sudo dhclient -v wlan0
```

Output:

```
//Meta infos...
Listening on LPF/wlan0/00:1e:65:bb:4e:ee
Sending on LPF/wlan0/00:1e:65:bb:4e:ee
Sending on Socket/fallback

DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 97 interval 3 (xid:0x18018e53)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 97 interval 4 (xid:0x18018e53)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 97 interval 5 (xid:0x18018e53)
//repeating
```

What do I miss here? If there're wrong credentials - how can I figure out some error message for that case? Is there a more detailed debug/verbose?

Comment: please edit and add the ouput of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `wpa_passphrase` when creating a configuration file for a WPA network. `wpa_passphrase` is included with the `wpa_supplicant` package.

Example:
`wpa_passphrase "nameOfWifi" "password" > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: Man page: http://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_passphrase

Comment: Thanks you made my day! Wasn't aware that my psk is a generated passsword - just thought its the plain password I enter when I use the GUI aswell :D

Comment: You are welcome :) Before the GUI sends your password to a WPA network, it actually encrypts it also!